# Android: Service started on boot, is not restarting when forced stop

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service which is successfully started on boot complete using a `BroadcastReceiver`. But when I am doing a force stop it is not restarting.

I tried starting the service from activity, and tried force stop, but in this case service restarted.

I am using `Service.START_STICKY`

In other question on stackoverflow, it is mentioned to user BaseContext not ApplicationContext. How do I get BaseContext from a `BroadcaseReceiver`

Comment: You should use applicationContext cause your service might live longer than other components.

Comment: I think ApplicationContext is the context available in onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver. How should I solve problem with the available Context ?

Comment: The `Context` you use to call `startService()` is completely irrelevant. What version of Android are you testing this on?

Answer (score -1):

START_STICKY restart service, when OS kill it. 
If you kill the app, it's not work.